# next.js home page not being displayed in storybook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, storybook

I am trying to run my next home page in storybooks, as it's my first time doing this I am trying to follow a tutorial, I created my next-app and initialised storybooks which runs just fine, now I want to import my homepage into storybooks, I do by creating a file `Home.stories.tsx` and put the following code in there :

```
import Home from "../pages/index"

// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-anonymous-default-export
export default {
    title : "Pages/Home",
    component : Home,
};

export const HomePage = () => <Home />
```

also to enable images I've put this into my preview.js file, the code :

```
import * as NextImage from "next/image"

const OriginalNextImage = NextImage.default;

Object.defineProperty(NextImage, "default", {
  configurable : true,
  value : (props) => < OriginalNextImage {...props} unoptimized />
})

export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
}
```

now when I run storybooks, I get the storybooks page but the Home page is not visible as I've attached in the ss below :
[image: localhost screenshot]

could someone please point out anything I'm missing or wrong with the code? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've been through the same thing.
Try removing initial contents in /pages/index.tsx
Maybe there's a problem with the inter from '@next/font/google'

Answer (score 0):

## Setup

Storybook now supports zero config NextJS setup.

Try creating a new Next JS and use the new `app/page` folder structure.

```
npx create-next-app@latest
```

Then add Storybook

```
npx sb init --builder webpack5
```

## Stories

I created an `app` folder inside Storybook's `stories` folder to mimic the NextJS folder structure.

Here is an example of a NextJS page rendering inside Storybook.

This file is located at `/stories/app/Home.stories.tsx`

```
import type { Meta, StoryObj } from '@storybook/react';

import Home from "../../app/page"

const meta: Meta<typeof Home> = {
  title: 'App/Page',
  component: Home,
  parameters: {
    // More on how to position stories at: https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/story-layout
    layout: 'fullscreen',
  },
};

export default meta;
type Story = StoryObj<typeof Home>;

export const _Home: Story = {};
```

## Images

Now to get images working, tell Storybook that Next's `public/` folder is a static directory.

Add `staticDirs` to your `.storybook/main.ts`

```
import type { StorybookConfig } from "@storybook/nextjs";
const config: StorybookConfig = {
  stories: ["../stories/**/*.mdx", "../stories/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions",
  ],
  framework: {
    name: "@storybook/nextjs",
    options: {},
  },
  docs: {
    autodocs: "tag",
  },
  staticDirs: ["../public"], // This loads images at localhost:6006/next.svg e.t.c.
};
export default config;
```

Comment: I'm getting `public` in the URI like `http://localhost:6006/public/fonts/...` when it's set up like this